# What is the minimum change to the last 3 lines of code that would make it work?

Tags: javascript

What is the minimum change to the last 3 lines of code that would make it work without adding or removing any lines of code?

```
<script>
function produceMessage(){
    var msg= 'This should print';
    return msg;
}

</script>

<div id="myDiv"> This should not print!</div>

<script>
    var element=document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML;
    var message= produceMessage();
    element=message;</script>
```

For example this is not what I'm looking for since it combines the last three lines of code into one:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML= produceMessage();
```

Comment: Is this homework, by any chance?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is one line of code bad?  In JavaScript, it's usually better to have smaller, cleaner code.

Comment: It's not homework, one line of code isn't bad, I'm just baffled why a simple document.write(message) or document.write(element) both print "this should print!" however you can't set element=message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from

```
<script>
    var element=document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML;
    var message=produceMessage();
    element=message;</script>
```

to

```
<script>
    var element=document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var message=produceMessage();
    element.innerHTML=message;</script>
```

.

---

The reason why your first one doesn't work is because you are assigning the **text** from the `myDiv` element to `var element`. Strings are primitive, so they are passed by value, meaning that a *copy* of the text from `.innerHTML` is copied into `var element`.

Rather than that, we want a *reference* to the HTML Element. Any non-primitive types are passed by reference by default in Javascript. To do that, we use

```
var element=document.getElementById('myDiv');
```

Now, `var element` points to the *same object* as the `document.getElementById('myDiv')`, rather than a different instance of the string from its `innerHTML`, meaning that when we modify the `element.innerHTML`, we also modify the same object as `document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML`, which happens to be the one on the DOM (web page), rather than a new and different copy of the string.

Comment: Beat me by a neat 26 seconds.

Comment: Thanks folks.  So my question is, why doesn't the original version work? a simple document.write(message) or document.write(element) both print "this should print!"

Comment: Because `innerHTML` does not point to element, rather, they originally pointed to the same thing.  You changed element's pointer to something new, but that doesn't make `innerHTML` change its pointer.

Comment: @LedZeppelin: I have updated my answer with an answer to your question.

Comment: @freedompeace, lol you really want that best answer don't you?

Comment: @LedZeppelin: I just like to help others :)

Answer (score 2):

freedompeace definitely got it right, I just wanted to add why your code was failing.

Setting element = message doesn't do anything because you didn't end up doing anything with element. The variable element is **not a reference** to the innerHTML of 'myDiv', but rather is just a container holding the text " This should not print!". So, when you say element = message, you are just changing what the container 'element' holds instead of changing the innerHTML of 'myDiv'.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function produceMessage(){
    var msg= 'This should print';
    return msg;
}

</script>

<div id="myDiv"> This should not print!</div>

<script>

    var element=document.getElementById('myDiv');

    var message= produceMessage();

    element.innerHTML=message;
</script>
```

I Think that should work. Originally you were just getting a string and changing your copy of that string, not updating the objects property.